# Disallow processes from preventing logout

Tags: gnome, logout

Processes that query the user to confirm exit can prevent GNOME from logging out so how can we disallow processes from preventing logout?

We've had issues with users attempting to logout -> walking away from the machine without realizing it was waiting for a response.

The machine in question uses GNOME 2.28.2.  Things I've tried:

- Looked through all the configuration options available with `gconftool-2`
- Googled for others trying to solve this problem (strangely enough: not one found)
- Looked at STIG rules for [RHEL6](https://people.redhat.com/swells/scap-security-guide/tables/table-rhel6-stig.html)/[RHEL7](https://people.redhat.com/swells/scap-security-guide/tables/table-rhel7-stig.html), expecting this would be a problem they'd want resolved, but nothing similar is mentioned

One possibility has occurred but I haven't gone down this path yet:

- `logout prompt: true`
- `logout command: [something relevant]`

... though I'm unsure what would be a sane/reasonable thing to run.  `pkill -u $UID` would probably get it done but also seems potentially problematic and/or excessive.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I didn't find a solution to the original question, but we did find a few workarounds:

1. Run the process through ssh: `ssh -X $(hostname) /path/to/script`
2. Run it under a separate X session

Without going into detail: (2) makes a lot more sense in our situation than it would for the more general case (a workstation), though the simplicity of (1) makes it attractive.